# Count images of spacific div using testNG + selenium rc

Tags: regex, selenium, selenium-rc, testng

How to count images in specific div using testNG + selenium rc of web page.

Answer (score 0):

selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='table1']/tr]").intValue(); which counts tr in that table.. likewise you can count modifying the xpath.